# How to use a string to get the respective image drawable

Tags: android, imageview

```
private int imageres[] = {
    R.drawable.desk,
    R.drawable.bed,
    R.drawable.chair,
};

private String typeofplace[] = {
    "Desk", //0
    "Bed", //1
    "Desk", //2
    "Chair", //3
    "Bed", //4
    "Chair", //5
};

for (int i = 0; i < typeofplace.length; i++) {
    //how do I get the image (int) based on the `typeofplace`:
    // MyFunction(imageres[R.drawable.{typeofplace}]);
}
```

Dow do I get the image (int) based on the `typeofplace`:

```
MyFunction(imageres[R.drawable.{typeofplace}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is a better approach to do that, you don't need a HashMap or a string array with the typeofplace. If you know the name of your drawable, simply use:

```
int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier("desk", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: So I can use this inside the forloop, and replace `desk` with the array index?

Comment: The point is that if you know the name of your drawable, for example, desk (the resource will be R.drawable.desk) and you want to use it, you can use just the line that I wrote to get the id, so you don't need to save in a hashmap the name, "desk", and the resource R.drawable.desk, because the system can find for you the drawable if you give it the name.

Comment: Disadvantage is that of the resource has to be the same as the resource name. Desk wil referfer to R.drawable.desk. If you're gonna use other formats like R.drawable.ic_desk you've got a problem.

Comment: For some reason I have it working but even through the drawable exist some of them doesn't show up

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < typeofplace.length; i++) {
        doSomething(getResources().getIdentifier(typeofplace[i], "drawable", getPackageName());
}`

Comment: AHA!!! Now it makes sense because some of them have space for the typeofplace and doesn't have in imageres...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashMap:

```
private String typeofplace[] = {
    "Desk", //0
    "Bed", //1
    "Desk", //2
    "Chair", //3
    "Bed", //4
    "Chair", //5
};

...

HashMap hm = new HashMap();
// Put elements to the map
hm.put("Desk", R.drawable.desk);
hm.put("Bed", R.drawable.bed);

for (int i = 0; i < typeofplace.length; i++) {
    doSomething(hm.get(typeofplace[i]));
}
```

Comment: So will I need one instance of, let's say Desk and it will work no matter how many times it appears? I have the other two variables and now I am creating a third one?

Comment: change just MyFunction(hm.get("Bed"));

Comment: So I think I can get rid of the entire `imageres` array than... am I right?

Comment: Yes, imageres can be removed since we will use a HashMap instead. I changed also the example code, I hope you will understand it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. So much easier :)

Comment: I get this error: `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`

Comment: Am I using, `import java.util.HashMap;`?

Comment: Correct, you have to use `import java.util.HashMap;` For some reason I don't get an error.

Comment: I get this warning when I initialize: `HashMap is a raw type. References to generic type HashMap<K,V> should be parameterize`

Comment: Do it like this: `HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();`